# Lost tablet - No SIM, no google account, no tracking software, can I track it?

Tags: tablet, gps-tracking

A couple of days ago, I lost my dear Android tablet. I dont know if I have left it somewhere or if it in fact was stolen :/
It does not have any 3G module, and hence no SIM, inserted. I haven't logged into my Google Account on the tablet. And I have not installed any tracking software.

The tablet have a GPS installed. Is there any way to track the tablet using only the serial-number?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You report the loss or theft to the police, and give them the serial number. (You'll need proof that it was yours, of course.) If someone finds it and hands it in, or if it's recovered from the thief, then they know it is yours, and will return it to you.

That's your only option. Since you haven't signed into your account on the tablet, as far as it's concerned, it doesn't belong to you. You can't remote-deploy tracking software onto it or enable Google's Android Device Manager. The GPS itself doesn't help you at all: it only tells the tablet where it is, not anyone else.

Comment: I know it's bad form to answer questions that you're VTCing. Sorry, I wrote the answer before VTCing.

Comment: You also forgot the options of the thief feeling bad and just returning the tablet, or the owner finding it by chance ;)

Comment: @Chahk Well, neither of those ways use the serial number, so they don't match what the user asked for :-p